# When I add items to my cart I can only add 9 items and item added to fire base but not shown in my cart page

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]
*When I add items to my cart I can only add 9 items and item added to fire base are not shown in my cart page*

Comment: I see you are new to StackOverflow. Welcome, welcome.
Please read how to ask questions here to help others to understand your problem. Thank you!
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.